# Macbook pro Manjaro bluetooth not working

Tags: macos, bluetooth, manjaro

I'm not sure if this is the write place to write my question, but here it is.
Before a week i updated my macbook pro early 2015 with manjaro gnom.
All good, but the bluetooth is not working.
I tried with bluetooth-manager but it's not opening and inside the `journalctl -f` it's showing

```
 Oct 15 20:08:59 PPeev systemd[1095]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Oct 15 20:09:00 PPeev blueman-manager.desktop[5014]: blueman-manager 20.09.00 ERROR    Manager:118 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.
Oct 15 20:09:00 PPeev blueman-manager.desktop[5014]: blueman-manager 20.09.00 ERROR    Manager:122 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting
Oct 15 20:09:00 PPeev blueman-manager.desktop[5014]: blueman-manager version 2.1.3 starting
Oct 15 20:09:00 PPeev systemd[1095]: gnome-launched-blueman-manager.desktop-5014.scope: Succeeded.
Oct 15 20:09:04 PPeev systemd[1095]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Succeeded.
```

Also when i check the status systemctl status bluetooth

```
    ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-10-15 19:52:23 EEST; 19min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1083 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9413)
     Memory: 2.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1083 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Oct 15 19:52:23 PPeev bluetoothd[1083]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEScanIntervalConnect” in group “Controller”
Oct 15 19:52:23 PPeev bluetoothd[1083]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEScanWindowConnect” in group “Controller”
Oct 15 19:52:23 PPeev bluetoothd[1083]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEMinConnectionInterval” in group “Controller”
Oct 15 19:52:23 PPeev bluetoothd[1083]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEMaxConnectionInterval” in group “Controller”
Oct 15 19:52:23 PPeev bluetoothd[1083]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEConnectionLatency” in group “Controller”
Oct 15 19:52:23 PPeev bluetoothd[1083]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEConnectionSupervisionTimeout” in group “Controller”
Oct 15 19:52:23 PPeev bluetoothd[1083]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEAutoconnecttimeout” in group “Controller”
Oct 15 19:52:23 PPeev systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Oct 15 19:52:23 PPeev bluetoothd[1083]: Starting SDP server
Oct 15 19:52:23 PPeev bluetoothd[1083]: Bluetooth management interface 1.17 initialized
```

Is running.

Answer (score 0):

try disabling and re-enabling the bluetooth from the bios menu.
I checked some threads, and the only working option i got is this.
You may try this. I guess it will work for you too.